# Javascript Json Parser

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to write a JSON parser using only javascript. The reason I only want to use javascript is that I want to parse the result returned from an API on server side in Meteor. However, I am having trouble parsing it. Below is the JSON returned:

```
{
   "R_5N4205x1hhF6pGZ":{
      "ResponseSet":"Default Response Set",
      "Name":"Anonymous",
      "ExternalDataReference":"",
      "EmailAddress":"",
      "Status":"16",
      "StartDate":"2014-01-09 11:19:51",
      "EndDate":"2014-01-09 11:19:56",
      "Finished":"1",
      "Q1":"Hello "
   },
   "R_7mqYPn4rZfNtVif":{
      "ResponseSet":"Default Response Set",
      "Name":"Anonymous",
      "ExternalDataReference":"",
      "EmailAddress":"",
      "Status":"16",
      "StartDate":"2014-01-09 11:21:58",
      "EndDate":"2014-01-09 11:22:05",
      "Finished":"1",
      "Q1":"Name identifier"
   },
   "R_bHs2h06HSQ1h2Qh":{
      "ResponseSet":"Default Response Set",
      "Name":"Anonymous",
      "ExternalDataReference":"",
      "EmailAddress":"",
      "Status":"16",
      "StartDate":"2014-01-09 11:28:24",
      "EndDate":"2014-01-09 11:28:30",
      "Finished":"1",
      "Q1":"Test"
   },
   "R_20rlmxxgGkYnWWF":{
      "ResponseSet":"Default Response Set",
      "Name":"Some, Name",
      "ExternalDataReference":"",
      "EmailAddress":"",
      "Status":"0",
      "StartDate":"2014-01-09 12:21:15",
      "EndDate":"2014-01-09 12:21:27",
      "Finished":"1",
      "Q1":"hjjhhjhj"
   },
   "R_e36yuRbnMmh38dD":{
      "ResponseSet":"Default Response Set",
      "Name":"Anonymous",
      "ExternalDataReference":"",
      "EmailAddress":"",
      "IPAddress":"161.185.153.4",
      "Status":"0",
      "StartDate":"2014-01-09 12:23:04",
      "EndDate":"2014-01-09 12:23:11",
      "Finished":"1",
      "Q1":"hello world "
   }
}
```

I want to save each response object with an object parent key as key "responseID": value (i.e  `array["responseID"]="R_e36yuRbnMmh38dD`")

```
  "R_e36yuRbnMmh38dD":{
      "ResponseSet":"Default Response Set",
      "Name":"Anonymous",
      "ExternalDataReference":"",
      "EmailAddress":"",
      "IPAddress":"161.185.153.4",
      "Status":"0",
      "StartDate":"2014-01-09 12:23:04",
      "EndDate":"2014-01-09 12:23:11",
      "Finished":"1",
      "Q1":"hello world "
   }
```

I want to save the resulting set in mongoDb.

Comment: So you're using Node.js, which has a built-in JSON parser?

Comment: i am new to meteor and node.js, any advice or suggestion will be greatly appreciated. So far  i have been only searching for json javascript parser online.

Comment: i can do it with jquery on the client side but i need to be able to do it on server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NodeJS JSON.parse() function but if I understand you want more create an object with the key in the object.

here is the code, if it is what you want to do :

```
var originalObject;
var resultArray;
for (var key in originalObject) {
   if(originalObject.hasOwnProperty(key )){
     var obj = originalObject[key];
     obj.responseID = key;
     resultArray.push(obj);
   }
}
```

But your question is a bit confusing. for mongoDB, I suggest the [nodejs native driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/)

Comment: how can i access the responseID inside thru each iteration?

Comment: got it! THANK YOU!
for (var x in resultArray)
{
    console.log(resultArray[x].Name);
}

Answer (score 1):

I don't *think* you're talking about a JSON parser - you seem to be saying you want to transform some already-parsed objects, in particular adding a new property to each. Although your example doesn't show that, and there is no `array`, so this is pure guesswork.

```
var responses_map = JSON.parse('{"R_5N4205x1hhF6pGZ": { "ResponseSet": ...');
```

You can get the strings of members of an object using `Object.keys`:

```
Object.keys(responses_map).forEach(function(response_id) {
    responses_map[response_id].responseID = response_id;
});

// now responses_map.R_5N4205x1hhF6pGZ.responseID is "R_5N4205x1hhF6pGZ"
```

(nb: assumes modern JavaScript - if your code also needed to run on IE8 you would need to use a `for response_id in response_map` loop instead of `Object.keys`.)

Comment: i am trying to loop thru all the values stored in each object with :
for (var key in response_map)
{
    var obj= response_map[key];
    console.log(obj.responseId);
}
But it returns undefined. how do i access the responseId value?

Comment: `obj.responseId` will be undefined, as it's not present in the object until you write it. You would want to do `obj.responseId = key`. Note if you use a `for...in` loop you should also use `hasOwnProperty` as in Yoann's answer to avoid problems with unwanted inheritance from `Object`.