# how to seggregate the json values in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, highcharts

I am new to javascript. I am trying out the `node.js`. I have a `json` as below:

```
{"releasename":null,"productline":"Replication","testplanname":"11.1 - Golden Integration-Regression Tests - Pass 3","resultoutcome":"Passed"},{"releasename":null,"productline":"FSM","testplanname":"11.1 - Golden Integration-Regression Tests - Pass 3","resultoutcome":"Blocked"},{"releasename":null,"productline":"FSM","testplanname":"11.1 - Golden Integration-Regression Tests - Pass 3","resultoutcome":"Blocked"}
```

I want to show how many `passed` status in the resultoutcome in the corresponding productline

For example:`'Framework'` passed is 10 and `'FSM'` blocked is 20 like that.

I want to save the `'productline'` values in one variable.and i have plot a bar chart dynamically using the variable.

Can anyone suggest me??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Json Parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032923/javascript-json-parser)

Comment: The sample you have provided isn't a JSON. Maybe after you wrap it in square brackets?

Answer (score 1):

I can roughly tell how to do it.
1. parse json to js object, like the following:

```
var data = JSON.parse("[{...}, {...}]") // you should change your original json to be like [{...}, {...}, {...}]
```

2. reduce, check lodash or use the build-in array functions if you are using modern browser:

   _.reduce(data, function(ret, item){
       if (item.resultoutcome !== 'Passed') {
           return ret;
       }
       ret.productline = 1 + (ret.productline || 0);
   }, {});
3. use D3 library to draw it, it is easy, just take a look quickstart at D3 official page.

Hope that help.

Cheers, 
Ron

Answer (score 0):

that's a perfect match for the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function:

```
a=[
    {
        "productline": "Replication",
        "releasename": null,
        "resultoutcome": "Passed",
        "testplanname": "11.1 - Golden Integration-Regression Tests - Pass 3"
    },
    {
        "productline": "FSM",
        "releasename": null,
        "resultoutcome": "Blocked",
        "testplanname": "11.1 - Golden Integration-Regression Tests - Pass 3"
    },
    {
        "productline": "FSM",
        "releasename": null,
        "resultoutcome": "Blocked",
        "testplanname": "11.1 - Golden Integration-Regression Tests - Pass 3"
    }
```

];

```
function passed_counter(aggr, item) {
   return (item.resultoutcome === 'Passed' ? 1 : 0 + aggr);
}

arr.reduce(passed_counter, 0);
```

explanation:
it iterates through each element of your array and runs the callback against it.
the initial value for aggr is 0 but it'll increase every time it meets a 'Passed'